# FFMpeg mux mp4 format result in streams not in file

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg, i have spend more than 10 days on finding any way to do muxing in mp4 format with audio and vedio in streams buffer not in file.
What i want is to mux mp4 format audio & vedio in a streams.

I am able to do muxing mp4 format in file. But not able to get mux mp4 format in streams buffer.

Till now i have tried this:
avio_alloc_context(avio_ctx_buffer, avio_ctx_buffer_size, 1, &bd, NULL, &write_packet, NULL);
By calling this avio_alloc_context and passing reference of write_packet function. I am able to get call write_packet. But when i write the data coming in write_packet in a file, and making mp4 file with that. The resultant mp4 file is not working. There is no vedio or audio information available by watching this file in Media Info.
The header is written , then loop is written and finally trailer is written, but not getting success in running final file.

Is there any good way to do mux in mp4 format in streams, so please tell me.

Kindly help to me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear to me what "in streams" means in this context. Please clairify.

Comment: Sorry if am not able to clerify well what i want.I want to get mux data in buffer ,  i want ffmpeg to not write mux data in file directly